# What apps can turn an android phone into bluetooth keyboard and mouse/touchpad?

Tags: android, mouse, bluetooth, keyboard, touchscreen

I am looking for an app that can turn an Android phone into a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse/touchpad. Recently I have bought a projector with built-in Android KitKat, but it requires a mouse and keyboard. Is it possible to turn my Android phone into a Bluetooth mouse/touchpad and keyboard for the projector? Thank you very much!

Comment: Far more than one, see my list for [Keyboard & Mouse](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc#group_649) apps. Had no need yet to try one, so I can give no personal recommendation here – but my guess would be [Unified Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Relmtech.Remote) for more than keyboard & mouse, or [Air HID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.androidTools.Air_HID_Demo_1m) for only keyboard & mouse.

Comment: I think I got it.

Comment: Glad to read (even though it's not on my list – and due to not being in any of the stores I trust, cannot be added). Enjoy – and thanks for placing the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Wukong remote and Wukong input perfectly resolves my problem. I have searched tons of remote bluetooth and wifi mouse and keyboard apps, whose server are all built for windows, Mac, or Linux. Wukong is the only one whose server is built for android system, such as smart TV and projector.

However, I do not think Wukong input is the exact name because I can not find it on google play store. The link is **[here](http://www.wukongtv.com/)**, for your reference. Sorry the website is not in English.